# Ethers.js: Solidity method arguments of type "contract": Error: invalid address or ENS name

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethers.js

I'm trying to invoke the following solidity function from ethersjs
(it takes another contract as argument):

```
function getReservesData(IPoolAddressesProvider provider) public view override ...
```

I tried this code:

```js
 const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(env.network);
 
 const contract = new ethers.Contract(
            '0x...'
            [ ...], // contract json abi
            provider
        );

const poolAddressProvider = new ethers.Contract(
            '0x...'
            [ ...], // pool address provider json abi
            provider
        );

await contract.getReservesData(poolAddressProvider);
```

I get the following error:

```
core.mjs:6484 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: invalid address or ENS name (argument="name", value="[object Object]", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.5.0)
Error: invalid address or ENS name (argument="name", value="[object Object]", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.5.0)
```

Probably I'm missing some key information on how to pass a contract type parameter.

Comment: Which line throws the error? What value are you passing on that line?

Comment: The line that throws the error is the last one. In which I try to invoke the contract's method passing another contract as argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Solidity function accepts a Solidity interface, which is ABI decoded from the `address` type.

So in JS, you need to pass the pool address as a `string` - not the `ethers.js` instance of `Contract`.

```
const poolAddress = "0x123...";
await contract.getReservesData(poolAddress);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this approach before. In this case I'm able to invoke the contract interface, but transaction is reverted: 

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: call revert exception (method="getReservesData(address)", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.5.0)
Error: call revert exception (method="getReservesData(address)", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.5.0)

Comment: @andreasimeoni That is a correct way to invoke the function. However your function reverted during runtime. This can be caused by numerous reasons, but host common causes for revert are: 1) failed `require()` condition, 2) failed internal call to a contract that is not deployed on the same network, 3) arithmetic error (e.g. overflow or division by zero)

Comment: I tried to call another method with similar signature, and your suggestion did work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use "0x123..." instead '0x123...', for some reason it won't parse address as string with '0x123...'